# InputStream does not read some files from a JAR

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, javalin

I've built a JAR file for my [Javalin](https://javalin.io) application, and the code runs just fine. However, reading some resource files from the JAR fails with `inputStream.available() == 0`, but it works just right for some other files.

The following files should be delivered just right:

```
a/
|\
| +- a.txt
| +- b.js
| +- c.css
|
b/
 \
  +- d.png
  +- e.txt
```

However, the `InputStream` only reads the files `a/a.txt`, `a/b.js` and `b/e.txt`. For all other files it returns nothing, and `available() == 0`, but it works when I'm not reading the files out of a JAR but from the extracted Classpath (and I'm using a `ClassLoader` no matter what the execution environment looks like). Also, the file size does not matter, `a/a.txt` is way larger than `a/c.css`, so I'm out of clues on this end.

Some example code (as I said, I'm using [Javalin](https://javalin.io) for the HTTP request/response, which is being handled in the [`ctx`](https://javalin.io/documentation#context) object, and I am also using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to detect the MIME-Type of the files requested, which works as expected):

```
// Example, real path is (correctly) fetched from the Context (ctx) object
String path = "a/c.css";

ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread ().getContextClassLoader ();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream (path);

String contentType = tika.detect (inputStream, path);
ctx.header ("Content-Type", contentType);

if (contentType.contains ("text") || contentType.contains ("script")) {
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader (inputStream);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (streamReader);

    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
    while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
        builder.append (line).append ("\n");
    }

    String result = builder.toString ();
    ctx.header ("Content-Length", String.valueOf (result.length ()));
    ctx.result (result);

    reader.close ();
} else {
    ctx.header ("Content-Length", String.valueOf (inputStream.available ()));
    ctx.result (inputStream);
}
```

Am I missing something here or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: available() doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, you could say that it is useless. So, if you're using it, you're doing something wrong and it won't work. Try to not use it at all and replace whatever you thought you were doing with it, with something else. That will work.

Comment: However, the HTTP client does not receive anything. In fact, the response for all files which have `available() == 0` is 0 bytes long when read out of the JAR. Anyhow, my code still does not work from the JAR when I remove all usages of `available()` from it (letting Jetty calculate the `Content-Length`)...

Comment: Obviously `tika.detect()` is consuming bytes from the input stream: in some cases, all of them.

Comment: @EJP I'd wager that would have been detected with the text files. InputStream offers mark(), which in all likelihood should work in all Java implementations for jar resources, and Tika is most likely using it.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner the response for files that have available() == 0 are empty, because you declare them to be zero-bytes long. Can you show what your code looks like when you're not using available(), and what exactly "doesn't work" mean? Your code really shouldn't go flip burgers. It's just suppose to produce some output given some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the MIME type detection might be the cause. First, try leaving it out and see whether that fixes your issue.

Here's my suspicion: `tika.detect()` obviously needs to consume bytes from the given stream to be able to detect anything. The [method javadocs](https://tika.apache.org/1.18/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect-java.io.InputStream-) state that it can only reset the stream if it supports marking. Thus, you should verify that the [`markSupported()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported()) of the `InputStream` returned by `classLoader.getResourceAsStream()` actually returns `true`.

If it doesn't, Tika might e.g. consume all of the content of a file until it can be sure about the file type, then be unable to reset the stream, and then there's nothing left for you to send to the client. In that case, you should wrap the original `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` (which adds the mark/reset feature) and use that for tika and for sending the content.

---

By the way: you should really use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure all input streams, stream reader and buffered readers are closed even when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I'm aware that my code lacks exception handling, I was currently only looking for a solution for this problem. Thank you, anyway!